# Scraping Google results c#

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

I'm scraping Google results using [ScrapySharp.Extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ScrapySharp/) and [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) for serialization and deserialization json results. I'm getting the results in form of text file, because results are encrypted. With regular expression and splitting I have removed the irrelevent stuff from my results but still there are so many irrelevent garbage in my array, I just need results. With every different query searched it gives different useless values. Is there any way to remove or clean my array? I just need results.

```cs
string[] separatingChars = { "null", ",", "[", "]", "\\n", "/d", "true", "NCSR", "*", "\\", "//", "//n", "\\/", "/", "\"u", "\"e", "\"c", "\":", "\"p", "\"d", "\")", "\"", "}", "{", "\"0", "\"38", "\"69", "\"]", "[\"", "www.google.com.tr"};

string[] words = result.Split(separatingChars, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
System.Console.WriteLine("{0} substrings in words:", words.Length);
```

This is my result:

```
"{\"e\":\"h2TSV9rDD8fzUO2WkKgD\",\"c\":0,\"u\":\"https:\\/\\/www.google.com.tr\\/s?tbm=mapfp=1\\u0026gs_ri=maps\\u0026suggest=p\\u0026authuser=0\\u0026hl=en\\u0026pb=!2i2!4m12!1m3!1d10453.125285380847!2d29.0052447!3d41.047225649999994!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i914!2i667!4f13.1!7i20!10b1!12m6!2m3!5m1!2b0!20e3!10b1!16b1!19m3!2m2!1i392!2i106!20m44!2m2!1i203!2i100!3m1!2i4!6m6!1m2!1i86!2i86!1m2!1i408!2i256!7m30!1m3!1e1!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e2!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e2!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e4!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e8!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b1!3e2!2b1!4b1!9b0!22m3!1shWTSV8-xF4PjUf20tMAG!3b1!7e81!23m1!4b1!24m5!2b1!5m1!5b1!10m1!8e3!26m3!2m2!1i80!2i92!37m1!1e81!47m0!49m1!3b1\\u0026q=taksim\\u0026pf=p\\u0026tch=1\\u0026ech=9\\u0026psi=hWTSV8-xF4PjUf20tMAG.1473406074800.1\",\"p\":true,\"d\":\")]}'\\n[[\\\"taksim\\\",[[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[[\\\"Taksim Square, Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\",null,null,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,\\\"BChIJY71WBmW3yhQRw7YgjLJYoIw\\\\u003d\\\",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]\\n,[\\\"Taksim Square\\\",[[0,6]\\n]\\n]\\n,[\\\"Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\"]\\n,0,0,null,null,[null,38,[69]\\n]\\n,null,null,null,[null,null,41.0370023,28.985091699999998]\\n,null,[[\\\"0x14cab7650656bd63:0x8ca058b28c20b6c3\\\",\\\"Taksim Square, Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\",null,[null,null,41.0370023,28.985091699999998]\\n,1,null,null,null,0]\\n,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]\\n,[\\\"Taksim Square, Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\",\\\"0x14cab7650656bd63:0x8ca058b28c20b6c3\\\",[null,null,41.0370023,28.985091699999998]\\n]\\n]\\n]\\n,[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[[\\\"Taksim, Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\",null,null,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,\\\"BChIJ08HkEGW3yhQRSdB1J8_42c8\\\\u003d\\\",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]\\n,[\\\"Taksim\\\",[[0,6]\\n]\\n]\\n,[\\\"Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\"]\\n,1,0,null,null,[null,38,[69]\\n]\\n,null,null,null,[null,null,41.0370485,28.9858443]\\n,null,[[\\\"0x14cab76510e4c1d3:0xcfd9f8cf2775d049\\\",\\\"Taksim, Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\",null,[null,null,41.0370485,28.9858443]\\n,0,null,null,null,0]\\n,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]\\n,[\\\"Taksim, Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\",\\\"0x14cab76510e4c1d3:0xcfd9f8cf2775d049\\\",[null,null,41.0370485,28.9858443]\\n]\\n]\\n]\\n,[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[[\\\"Harbiye Mahallesi, Taşkışla Caddesi, Şişli\\/İstanbul\\\",null,null,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]\\n,[\\\"Taşkışla Caddesi\\\",[[0,16]\\n]\\n]\\n,[\\\"Harbiye Mahallesi, Şişli\\/İstanbul\\\"]\\n,0,0,null,null,[null,38]\\n,null,null,null,[null,null,41.0444781,28.9903408]\\n,null,null,[\\\"Harbiye Mahallesi, Taşkışla Caddesi, Şişli\\/İstanbul\\\"]\\n]\\n]\\n,[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[[\\\"Taksim Station, Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\",null,null,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,\\\"BChIJO0h7PGW3yhQRD9N8fEEQZRI\\\\u003d\\\",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]\\n,[\\\"Taksim Station\\\",[[0,6]\\n]\\n]\\n,[\\\"Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\"]\\n,1,0,null,null,[null,38]\\n,null,null,null,[null,null,41.0367609,28.9864186]\\n,null,[[\\\"0x14cab7653c7b483b:0x126510417c7cd30f\\\",\\\"Taksim Station, Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\",null,[null,null,41.0367609,28.9864186]\\n,0,null,null,null,0]\\n,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]\\n,[\\\"Taksim Station, Gümüşsuyu Mahallesi, Beyoğlu\\/İstanbul\\\",\\\"0x14cab7653c7b483b:0x126510417c7cd30f\\\",[null,null,41.0367609,28.9864186]\\n]\\n]\\n]\\n,[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[[\\\"Rüstem Paşa Mahallesi, Tahmis Sokak, Fatih\\/İstanbul\\\",null,null,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]\\n,[\\\"Tahmis Sokak\\\",[[0,12]\\n]\\n]\\n,[\\\"Rüstem Paşa Mahallesi, Fatih\\/İstanbul\\\"]\\n,0,0,null,null,[null,38]\\n,null,null,null,[null,null,41.016564699999996,28.9703786]\\n,null,null,[\\\"Rüstem Paşa Mahallesi, Tahmis Sokak, Fatih\\/İstanbul\\\"]\\n]\\n]\\n]\\n,null,null]\\n,null,null,null,null,null,null,\\\"h2TSV9rDD8fzUO2WkKgD\\\",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]\\n\"}/*\"\"*/{\"e\":\"h2TSV-yhEcfzUO2WkKgD\",\"c\":0,\"u\":\"https:\\/\\/www.google.com.tr\\/search?tbm=mapfp=1\\u0026gs_ri=maps\\u0026suggest=p\\u0026authuser=0\\u0026hl=en\\u0026pb=!2i2!4m12!1m3!1d10453.125285380847!2d29.0052447!3d41.047225649999994!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i914!2i667!4f13.1!7i20!10b1!12m6!2m3!5m1!2b0!20e3!10b1!16b1!19m3!2m2!1i392!2i106!20m44!2m2!1i203!2i100!3m1!2i4!6m6!1m2!1i86!2i86!1m2!1i408!2i256!7m30!1m3!1e1!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e2!2b1!3e2!1m3!1e2!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e4!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e8!2b0!3e3!1m3!1e3!2b1!3e2!2b1!4b1!9b0!22m3!1shWTSV8-xF4PjUf20tMAG!3b1!7e81!23m1!4b1!24m5!2b1!5m1!5b1!10m1!8e3!26m3!2m2!1i80!2i92!37m1!1e81!47m0!49m1!3b1\\u0026q=taksim\\u0026pf=p\\u0026tch=1\\u0026ech=9\\u0026psi=hWTSV8-xF4PjUf20tMAG.1473406074800.1\\u0026oq=taksim\",\"p\":true,\"d\":\"\\\"NCSR\\\"\"}/*\"\"*/"
```

Comment: [How to return search result in XML](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/24/syndicated/398/Posts/10006/how-to-return-search-result-in-xml.aspx)

Comment: You should provide some more code and the file that you are working with so we can understand the question fully.

Comment: Can you give an example of the (json) data you receive? I suspect you are over-complicating things by messing with json data as a string instead of de-serialzing it.

Comment: @user3060520 The things described there look a little outdated to me.

Comment: I have updated my question with example, have a look

Comment: So what wrong with de-serializing it?

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you should try to fetch the Google Search results in a structured way. Using Custom Search API might provide you this, see https://developers.google.com/custom-search/.

If you still want to parse the human readable webpage, then it is better to get the meaningful data out by using a Web page parser and then take out the data you need by querying the DOM. This should work much better then trying to use RegEx on the whole page.

Try the Html Agility Pack library (http://html-agility-pack.net available via Nuget). Html Agility Pack can be used to parse HTML4 and HTML5 by using the LoadHtml method. Once you have done that you can do something like this to parse posts which is much better then regular expressions:

```
var commonPosts = root.Descendants().Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("common-post"));
```

Comment: The custom search you linked doesn't allow to query public google search results like the OP intends to do and the OP already uses a lib to scrape so there's no need for Html Agility Pack.

Comment: Html Agility Pack can be used to parse HTML4 and HTML5 by using the LoadHtml method. Once you have done that you can do something like this to parse posts which is much better then regular expressions: var commonPosts = root.Descendants().Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("common-post"));